# Rspec - Stubbing gets.chomp out of the constructor

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing a Mastermind game in Ruby and in the constructor of the class 'Game' I want to use gets.chomp to ask the user for its name. Pretty easy, but where I run into trouble is when testing this class in RSpec, but I can't seem to properly stub out 'gets' and 'puts', because they are in the constructor not a regular method.

```
class Game
  def initialize
    puts "Please enter your name:"
    @player = Player.new(gets.chomp)
  end
end

describe Game do
  Game.stub(:gets).and_return("Create Code AI")
  Game.stub(:puts)
  subject(:game) { Game.new }

  describe "#new" do
    its("player.name") { eql("Create Code AI") }
  end
end

class Player
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

I've also tried putting the stubs into 'before' and 'let' blocks amongst other things, but nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Although this is certainly possible, you should consider refactoring your code. Wouldn't it be much easier if you could initialize a `Game` without stubbing `gets` and `puts`?

Comment: I think that's the best way to go about it yeah, thanks! The answer down below, although it may very well be correct, seems way too complex for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have a method which captures stdin and stdout to help with the testing in cases like these:

```
require 'stringio'

module Kernel
  def capture_stdout(console_input = '')
    $stdin = StringIO.new(console_input)
    out = StringIO.new
    $stdout = out
    yield
    return out.string.strip
  ensure
    $stdout = STDOUT
    $stdin = STDIN
  end
end
```

Now, let's assume I want to test a method that interacts with stdin/stdout:

```
def greet
  name = gets
  puts "Welcome, #{name}!"
end
```

I would write the following test:

```
require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.describe '#say_name' do
  it 'prints name correctly' do
    input = 'Joe'
    result = capture_stdout(input) do
      greet
    end

    expect(result).to eql 'Welcome, Joe!'
  end
end
```

---

I presented the example above to illustrate how to test both console input and output.

In your case, the test could look like this:

```
describe Game do
  subject(:game) do
    capture_stdout('Create Code AI') { return Game.new }
  end

  describe "#new" do
    its("player.name") { eql("Create Code AI") }
  end
end
```

Note: In order for this to work, `#player` should be an accessible member of `Game`. So, you may want to add this to your `Game` class:

```
attr_reader :player
```

Comment: Thanks!

This seems too complex for what I'm doing though (I sort of understand it, but not 100%), so I think I'll go with the other guy's comment and take the puts + gets out of the constructor and put them into a different method, which should be easier to stub.

Comment: @FrankPeelen Yes, that's good advice. Stub `gets` and `puts` when you have no other choice (ex: there's existing legacy code you need to test). I personally use this technique to write answers for codegolf.stackexchange.com, when I explicitly have to use stdin/out.